# error of drawing angles by using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-angles

I draw an angle：

```
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate [label=above right:$A$] (A) at (1,1);
    \coordinate [label=above left:$B$] (B) at (0,0);
    \coordinate [label=below left:$C$] (C) at (1,0);
    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) pic [draw] {angle};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get:
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/pics/angle' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. ...draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) pic [draw] {angle}.

How to solve it?

Comment: It works for me!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your code snippet is not a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). If I place it in a minimal document, I get no error and the expected output is shown.

Comment: I had placed it in a document,but I got the error "I do not know the key '/tikz/pics/angle'".Actually,I wonder know what does it means and how to solve the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I insert your code fragment into a small document, for example:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate [label=above right:$A$] (A) at (1,1);
    \coordinate [label=above left:$B$] (B) at (0,0);
    \coordinate [label=below left:$C$] (C) at (1,0);

    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) pic [draw] {angle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the following result:

[image]

But I guess that you probably looking for the following result:

[image]

The MWE (Minimal Working Example) that produces the image above, unlike your code fragment, has angular coordinates explicitly defined by `{angle=C--B--A}`. Note, the order of those coordinates determine if angle mark is inside or outside drawn lines:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate [label=above right:$A$] (A) at (1,1);
    \coordinate [label= left:$B$] (B) at (0,0);
    \coordinate [label=right:$C$] (C) at (1,0);
    
    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) pic [draw] {angle=C--B--A}; % <---
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also another(similar) approach using `tkz-euclide` package:

```
\documentclass{standalone}    
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}    
\tkzSetUpPoint[size=1,color=black,fill=black]    
\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}    
        \tkzDefPoints{1/1/A,0/0/B,1/0/C}    
        \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)    
        \tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C)    
        \tkzLabelPoint[above](A){A}\tkzLabelPoint[left](B){B}  \tkzLabelPoint[right](C){C}    
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](C,B,A)     
    \end{tikzpicture}     
\end{document}
```

and the output:
[image]